# Avoiding string literals to reduce memory allocations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, should we avoid string literals in frequently executed methods (like `Update()`) to avoid unnecessary memory allocations and instead store string values into fields?

```
class TouchInputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // private string messageVar = "OnFingerMove";
    /* ... */
    private void HandleFingerMove(Finger finger)
    {
        /* ... */
        gameObj.SendMessage("OnFingerMove");
        // vs.
        // gameObj.SendMessage(messageVar);
    }
}
```

I assume that the string literal "OnFingerMove" will allocate new memory on every frame. Will the compiler somehow optimize string literals to reduce garbage? I've read some articles that suggest avoiding string concatenation in methods executed on every frame, so I started wondering if string literals would also create garbage in the heap.

Comment: _"I assume that the string literal "OnFingerMove" will allocate new memory on every frame"_ - I would assume the opposite. By default C# compiler will intern string literals.

Comment: ChatGPT said this: "relying solely on compiler optimizations for string literals may not always be sufficient, especially in performance-critical scenarios. It's still a good practice to manually optimize your code where possible, such as by storing frequently used string literals". I don't trust ChatGPT completely, so I posted the question here

Comment: *I assume* - you don't need to assume, you can ask `string.IsInterned()` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isinterned?view=net-8.0

Comment: Where does this advice come from?  Constant strings are a compile time thing, not a runtime thing.

Comment: @SrdjanPazin ChatGPT is designed to generate text which looks like something a person would say, actual correctness is not always achieved.

Comment: @Neil From ChatGPT. I can make it non-constant. The only thing that was important for me is to store the string in a field

Comment: ChatGPT is technically correct. The problem is that you have ignored the most important part of its output: "**may** not always be sufficient". In a typical Unity game, string allocations are never going to be a performance factor. Ever. You are also falling foul of the premature optimisation fallacy - don't try to optimise up-front, optimise if and only if you need to.

Comment: If you add `const` to the the commented out example vs the current code, the result would be identical (The IDE should tell you to add const).  Also, you should measure if this makes any difference to you (benchmarks).  Do not put 100% trust in anything AI tells you, it's just creating words by statistics, there is no intelligence involved.